# Change default SFTP directory in Cygwin

Tags: sshd, sftp, cygwin

On a Windows server, I've installed OpenSSH via Cygwin to mainly connect via SFTP.
I would like to change the default directory for the SFTP server.
When I log via ssh to this server, my entry point is in `/home/mquser`.
I would like to set the default directory for SFTP in `/home/mquser/ftproot`. I tried to add to my `sshd_config` the following part, but when I login via SFTP I keep always goint to `/home/mquser` instead of `/home/mquser/default`

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group mqm
    ForceCommand internal-sftp 
    ChrootDirectory /home/mquser/ftproot
```

Comment: Can we assume you restarted the SSH server after changing the config?  I only ask because it's not mentioned in the question.  There's a reasonably comprehensive wiki describing chroot for SFTP here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/SFTP_chroot

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have restarted the server after the changes to the configuration. I looked at the wiki and it seems to me I've done all the steps right, but I keep loggin on my default user's home